# How to store a temporary value in a Postgresql query and then use it multiple times?

Tags: postgresql

I have this simple query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CompressorAlerts
WHERE CAST('2020-09-20' as timestamp) IS NULL OR faultTimestamp >= CAST('2020-09-20' as timestamp)
```

(I hardcoded `2020-09-20` ... it is really a value I am getting from somewhere else, irrelevant to this question, but I hardcoded it for simplicity).

As you can see, I am repeating twice `CAST('2020-09-20' as timestamp)`. I want to avoid that, so I tried doing this:

```sql
WITH myDate as (SELECT CAST('2020-09-20' as timestamp))
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CompressorAlerts
WHERE myDate IS NULL OR faultTimestamp >= myDate
```

However, I get this error: `column "mydate" does not exist`.

How can I reference the `myDate` value I defined in the `WITH` clause? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If the date is actually a parameter then why can't you use `where ? is null or faulttimestamp >= ?`(or whatever parameter placeholder you use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mydate` is the name of the CTE, not the name of the column expression inside it. Additionally you need to include the CTE in the `FROM` part of the query.

```
WITH params (mydate) as (
  values (timestamp '2020-09-20')
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CompressorAlerts, params
WHERE mydate IS NULL 
   OR faultTimestamp >= mydate
```